# Unable to create emulator using AVD in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, android-emulator

I am unable to create new emulators / virtual devices in android studio.

I can go through the motions of creating a new emulator within Android Studio and there are no errors.  I even get the progress bar at the end like it is creating the new device, but following, no new device shows up and no errors are presented.  It just doesn't display any new devices.

Initially I was getting the message within the AVD that VT (virtualization) was not enabled in my BIOS and there was no KVM present.  I then followed the instructions found in an article on Stackoverflow which went through enabling VT in the BIOS as well as confirming my system was capable of using a KVM.  I then followed the instructions for setting up the KVM in Ubuntu and now no longer get any errors or warnings in AVD, but still cannot create an emulator.

I have verified within my SDK that I have all options enabled (all packages) for builds 16 - 24.

I am running Android Studio 2.1.2 on Ubuntu.  My version information for Ubuntu is shown below.

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

had to load a 32 bit library - libstdc++6